Passing args to a .net 8 app hosted as Azure Container Job
I'm trying to pass custom arguments to a .net 8 app hosted as Azure Container Job.
I created the job using bicep. I did not specify the args. The goal is to specify specific args when triggering it.
The project is defined like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ContainerRepository>myapp</ContainerRepository>
        <ContainerFamily>jammy-chiseled</ContainerFamily>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
</Project>

and published to the Azure Container Registry using the dotnet publish /t:PublishContainer.
The app itself reads the args at startup:
if (args.Length < 1)
{
    throw new Exception($"Usage: myapp [Path]. Args found: {args.Length}");
}

I'm trying to start it with the following az command:
az containerapp job start --name $name --subscription $subscriptionId -g $resourceGroupName --args "path_to_file"

In the logs I can see that the number of args is always 0.
How should I pass the args to the .net app?
Update
It seems that I can get the args if I configure the ContainerAppCommand:
    <ItemGroup Label="ContainerAppCommand Assignment">
        <ContainerAppCommand Include="dotnet" />
        <ContainerAppCommand Include="MyApp.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

I've got the idea from the docs, but the behavior is still unclear as this should anyway be the default as mentioned in the docs.
Update 2
It seems that the problem was not in the image, but in the behavior of the az containerapp job start command.
The configuration values (--command, --args, etc.) seem valid only when used with the --image arg.
I removed the ItemGroup from the csproj file and specified the full az command like this:
az containerapp job start --name $name --subscription $subscriptionId -g $resourceGroupName --image myacr.azurecr.io/myappimage --args "path_to_file" ...

And now I'm getting the expected args array.
Important: as mentioned in the docs, "When overriding the configuration, the job's entire template configuration is replaced with the new configuration. Ensure that the new configuration includes all required settings."

Is your issue resolved ?

@Harshitha yes, adding the answer.
The issue was with the az command used to call the job. It was not related to the definition of the container or the app.

Yes,please post your sol as an answer.

To pass custom --args to the container with the az containerapp job start command, you need to specify the --image.
This information can be found in the docs.
